# How do French people chant for sports, like how the English say, "Go! Go! Go!" ?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, sport

What do the French say when they are chanting at a sporting event? In English, people might say, "Go! Go! Go!", or chant the MVP's name/number while clapping rhythmically. What's a substitute for, 
"Go! Go! Go!"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In France, chanting is usual at soccer games. There's a lot of different songs depending on the club and players.

Here are some classics:

- "Qui ne saute pas n'est pas français" (for the French national team, but the end can be changed to whatever team you're supporting, eg "qui ne saute pas n'est pas marseillais") - meant to encourage people to jump in place to produce a giant rumble
- "Allez les Bleus" (again this would be for the national team based on the jersey color, but can be used for other teams by matching their jersey colors)
- Victory chants: "On a gagné" (for any victory), "On est en finale" (for a qualification for the finals of a tournament) and "On est les champions" for a championship win; "Et 1, et 2, et 3-0" for a large goal difference.

But really there are many club specific chants too, and sometimes the name of a particularly outstanding player will be chanted.

Here you can listen to some of them, as well as more recent, less popular creations just for this year's world cup: https://youtu.be/NdLRKQpdgUU

Comment: <mode_trolling>Soccer ? What's soccer ?</mode_trolling> Hmmm... very common in rugby too. However, most of them being... bawdy songs... Any non rugby-enthusiastic mod would blame me for singing them here! ;) No kidding! there is such a huge collection that the ASM sups are compiling them into an encyclopaedia.

Comment: @aCOSwt I'm less aware of the rugby ones. There aren't any chants at tennis games...

Comment: lol! In tennis ? Hmm... singing is not the fact of the jet set. Even when the jet set is made of singers ); Well more seriously, you are correct, no songs in individual games.

Comment: Some other common soccer chants in France and other French-speaking countries: chanting the name or the nickname of a player (but not the number - at least I have never heard that),eg "ZI-ZOU, ZI-ZOU" (Zidane's nickname), chanting "et 1, et 2 et 3-0" if that is the score (this became popular after France's 3-0 victory over Brazil in 1998), chanting "on est chez nous" (esp. sung by visiting supporters, as some sort of provoking the home supporters).

Comment: And let's not forget "I will survive"... :-)